# To the most part vs for the most part

Tags: idioms, synonyms

Currently

- "for the most part" yields 67.400.000
- "to the most part" yields 70.500.000

results on Google. Are these two phrases interchangeable? If not, when would you use which?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but "for the most part" sound very common, maybe more like everyday language than "to the most part".

Comment: [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+most+part) has the first, but not the second, which I would never use.

Comment: 1) When Googling, if you actually enclose the phrase in quote marks, you prioritize exact matches for the full phrase. Trying that, I get 3.21 million results for "for the most part" and 3.04 million results for "to the most part." I wonder whether you've been using the quote marks? 2) Have you examined the results of the "to the most part" query? When I remove the quote marks, the primary entry is a definition for the idiom "for the most part." With the quote marks, we get results like "Which one are you looking forward to the most? Part 1..."

Comment: 3) Number of results returned by a Google survey might be useful as a very quick back-of-the-envelope exercise, but [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+the+most+part%2Cfor+the+most+part&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20most%20part%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20most%20part%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20most%20part%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20most%20part%3B%2Cc0) would seem to put the matter to rest.

Answer (score 1):

It might change across nationalities but "for the most part" is definitely more common here in Australia to the point where "to the most part" sounds a bit strange, almost wrong. The two phrases are generally not used very commonly and, even in academic contexts, I would recommend "generally/in general" instead.

I.e Instead of "for the most part, viruses are smaller than bacteria" use "In general, viruses are smaller than bacteria" or "Viruses are generally smaller than bacteria"